# Error creating object in IE8

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    var APP= APP || {};
    APP.settings = {
        apiRoot: "http://localhost/appapi",
        siteRoot: "http://localhost",
    };
```

This code works in Chrome and Firefox but is throwing an error in IE8, `Unable to set value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined`

This isn't my code so I'm at a bit of a loss to why this isn't working?

Comment: My guess is that it is a reserved keyword. Try `settingss` to verify that

Comment: Yep, looks like your right - plus I needed to remove the final ',' char from the last 'setting'.

Comment: @EriG: Why would `settings` be a reserved word inside our own namespace? Do you have any information on that?

Comment: Maybe not a reserved word as such, is it a property of the window object? Still doesn't explain why when inside a namespace though.

Comment: @CLiown: It is highly unlikely that `settings` is a reserved word.

Comment: Just a side node. If you want to use a reserved in an object you can use braces. `APP["null"] = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the trailing comma in your object property list, which IE < 9 does not like and throws an error. Remove it and it will be fine.

```
var APP = APP || {};
APP.settings = {
    apiRoot: "http://localhost/appapi",
    siteRoot: "http://localhost" // <-- Comma removed here
};
```

Comment: This is the correct answer that settings isn't reserved in javascript.